# Use of "What have you understood?"

Tags: meaning, sentence

> I understood why you sent me the story.

I have to reply to the above statement.

Is it okay to reply to it as follows:

> What have you understood?

If my reply is wrong, could you suggest a correct one?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your question can never be answered without any context. Why did you send the story? What story? Why did he/she reply with "I understand why you sent me the story". What is the relationship between you and him/her? Your question received 3 downvotes and will be closed if you don't edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your reply ("What have you understood?") is grammatically correct but probably doesn't have the meaning that you intend.

In response to the sentence *"I understand why you sent me the story"*, the question you ask will depend heavily on the context. Without context, I am assuming the following:

- X sent Y a copy of a story.
- The reason why the story was sent may or may not have been explicit. For example, perhaps X wanted Y to proofread it, or offer criticism, or merely read and enjoy it.
- Y responded by confirming that he knew and understood the reason why X sent him the story (whether that reason was explicit or not).

At this point, if X were to ask, "What have you understood?" it wouldn't make much sense, because the *what* that Y understands is "the reason why X sent the story." In other words, at this point in the conversation, both X and Y should understand the reason why the story was sent.

Perhaps X is curious as to what Y's reaction was to the story. But if that were the case, the actual question posed would be different depending on the reason the story was sent. In general, I would expect that X would ask a question like:

> - What did you think about the story?
> - Do you have any feedback?
> - What was your reaction?